# CameraX - ImageProxy returned by ImageCapture is invalid

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit, android-camerax

I am using CameraX to capture an image and then using Firebase ML kit to recognise Text.

CameraX return ImageProxy in from ImageCapture when we take pic.

```
imageCapture.takePicture(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), new ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureSuccess(ImageProxy image, int rotationDegrees) {
                    super.onCaptureSuccess(image, rotationDegrees);

                    startTextRecognization(image, rotationDegrees);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ImageCapture.ImageCaptureError imageCaptureError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
                    super.onError(imageCaptureError, message, cause);

                }
            });
```

Passing that image to Firebase -

```
public void startTextRecognizing(ImageProxy imageProxy, int rotationDegrees) {
    this.imageProxy = imageProxy;
    this.rotationDegrees = rotationDegrees;

    if (imageProxy == null || imageProxy.getImage() == null) {
        return;
    }

    Image mediaImage = imageProxy.getImage();
    FirebaseVisionImage firebaseVisionImage =
            FirebaseVisionImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, rotationDegrees);

    FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
            .getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();

    Task<FirebaseVisionText> result =
            detector.processImage(firebaseVisionImage)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {
                            extractText(firebaseVisionText);
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.d("*Rahul", "Text Recognization Failed");
                        }
                    });

    //result.getResult();

}
```

I am getting an error-

```
issue capture request for camera 0
2020-02-12 18:27:27.497 6788-6842/com.example.myapplication D/CaptureSession: Issuing capture request.
2020-02-12 18:27:27.786 6788-7173/com.example.myapplication D/*Rahul:  Success Fully Captured - 
2020-02-12 18:27:27.794 6788-6788/com.example.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


--------- beginning of crash
2020-02-12 18:27:27.795 6788-6788/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 6788
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Image is already closed
    at android.media.Image.throwISEIfImageIsInvalid(Image.java:72)
    at android.media.ImageReader$SurfaceImage.getFormat(ImageReader.java:819)
    at com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage.fromMediaImage(com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@@24.0.1:6)
    at com.example.myapplication.TextRocognizationHelper.startTextRecognizing(TextRocognizationHelper.java:40)
    at com.example.myapplication.CameraActivity$3.run(CameraActivity.java:198)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)


--------- beginning of system
```

Can you help as, where i am doing wrong? The image returned by ImageCapture is coming invalid format.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `super.onCaptureSuccess(image, rotationDegrees)` it closes the image, so either move it after your text recognition method or remove the line and close the image yourself later by calling `image.close()`.

Off topic - what [CameraX version](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera) are you using? I didn't find the `ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedListener` class in the newest library version. You should use newest one available because it's still in alpha and the core api is changing (although the devs said that the newest at the time - alpha10 is near the beta release so the core api shouldn't change much now).